# why does Dagger injects concrete classes?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm new to `Dagger`, i used `Guice` before.

I have read this [tutorial](http://square.github.io/dagger/)

and I'm confused:

1) Why should I even use dagger to inject into concrete members?
After all the point of DI hide replaceable implementation under interfaces. no?

I mean I can inject into concrete member using Guice, but I would only do it when I want to inject a global singleton.

2) I sometimes see Module class with `Inject` annotation.
Why is that declaration needed? The compiler can refer this from the returned type of the methods with @Provides annotation. No?

And if that's needed, why is it missing sometimes? like in the example:

```
@Module
class DripCoffeeModule {
  @Provides Heater provideHeater() {
    return new ElectricHeater();
  }

  @Provides Pump providePump(Thermosiphon pump) {
    return pump;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant understand the point of your first question. if you mean dependency INVERSION by DI, it is different from dependency INJECTION. injection is just about getting the concern out of the classes and provide all their need out of them.

for your second question you need @inject annotation to say you need to fill only this variable from the dagger. maybe you have three other same type variable and you need to fill them yourself. assume string type, you may have a bunch of string variables in your class but you dont want all of them to be filled by what dagger provides so you just mention @inject to tell dagger fill the variable for you.

and to explain about your example i must say you dont need to annotate injecting variables with @inject in your module. since here is the place everything is provided Dagger already knows that he must provide all the method argument variables.

when you write a method in module you are providing something and Dagger will look for all of methods argument variables for you and fill them using other methods you provide for that. let me show you with an example:

```
@Module
class DripCoffeeModule 
{
   @Provides Heater provideHeater() 
   {
     return new ElectricHeater();
   }

   @Provides Pump providePump(Thermosiphon tPump) 
   {
     return tPump;
   }

   @Provides Thermosiphon provideThermosiphonPump() 
   {
     return new Thermosiphon();
   }
}
```

in the code above Dagger will provide tPump using the method providePump() you provided before. so you dont need to inform dagger to use injection in your module. it goes without saying.

whenever you inject a variable of type Pump, Dagger first finds a method in your module with the return type of Pump (providePump), then it recognizes it needs to create an instance of Thermosiphon object to do so. so it finds a method that can provide a Thermosiphon (provideThermosiphonPump), then runs that and gets the Thermosiphon object and gives it to providePump method and then provides the Pump object for you.